# How to select all rows where Field = '*'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I want to create simple query
where @_name can be "any value" like "*"

```
declare @_name nvarchar(120)

select * from 
table_1
whare Name =@_name
```

I want the query to be able to get  @_name as parameter with '*' and it will give me all the rows with all the Names Or in other scenario it will get  @_name ='Jack'
and will return only rows with Name='Jack'

may be there is a sign like '*' to tell the SQL get all rows ?

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE (Name =@_name OR @_name='*')
```

The idea is to treat asterisk `'*'` as a special value: when `@_name` is `'*'`, the `Name =@_name` portion is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that `name` could be `NULL`, the expression is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE (Name =@_name OR @_name='*' or Name is null and @Name is null)
```

I mention this because `NULL` is often used to mean "all" when using variables like this (rather than a special string like "*").